# Jquery image scroller slow and jerky

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I built this image scroller with little thumbnail images at the bottom, I wanted the thumbnails to scroll left and right when you hover over an indicated area and stop when the last one comes into view ( and the same with the first one for the other direction) The code that I came up with works for a little while on the page but after a while it starts to get slow and jerky so I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to accomplish the same thing.

The code is:

```
var licount = $('.hs_cos_flex-slides-thumb li').length; //counts rows in list
var thumbwidth = licount * 210; //gets width of all rows
var viewwidth = $(".hs-cos-flex-slider-control-panel").width(); //gets width of sarounding div
var scrollwidth = thumbwidth - viewwidth; //gets width where last row is visible

var intervalId = window.setInterval;

$( ".thumb-for" ).hover(
    function() {
        var scrollposition = $(".hs_cos_flex-slides-thumb").position().left; //calculates how far left it has moved
        var absposition = Math.abs(scrollposition); //gets absolute value of left movement
        var shover = true;

    if ( scrollwidth > (absposition + 209) ){  

            $('.hs_cos_flex-slides-thumb').animate({
                right: '+=210px'
            }, 1500, 'linear');
            absposition+=210;
        }

    intervalId = window.setInterval(moveticker, 1500)

    function moveticker() {


        if ( scrollwidth > (absposition + 209) ){  

            $('.hs_cos_flex-slides-thumb').animate({
                right: '+=210px'
            }, 1500, 'linear');
            absposition+=210;
        }



    };


}, function() {

    window.clearInterval(intervalId);

  }
);


$( ".thumb-back" ).hover(
    function() {
        var scrollposition = $(".hs_cos_flex-slides-thumb").position().left; //calculates how far left it has moved
        var absposition = Math.abs(scrollposition); //gets absolute value of left movement
        var shover = true;

    if ( scrollposition < 0 ){  

            $('.hs_cos_flex-slides-thumb').animate({
                right: '-=210px'
            }, 1500, 'linear');
            scrollposition+=210;
        }

    intervalId = window.setInterval(moveticker, 1500)

    function moveticker() {


        if ( scrollposition < 0 ){  

            $('.hs_cos_flex-slides-thumb').animate({
                right: '-=210px'
            }, 1500, 'linear');
            scrollposition+=210;
        }



    };


}, function() {

    window.clearInterval(intervalId);

  }
);
```